# How do I (and should I) move a question to SuperUser?

Tags: support, scope, best-practice

First I asked [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/424015/what-bunch-of-ffmpeg-scripts-do-i-need-to-run-video-for-everybody) at superuser which required me to upgrade away from Ubuntu's ancient ffmpeg.  Then I asked [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139570/how-do-i-remove-all-metadata-from-a-quicktime-movie-file) at Ask Ubuntu whose answer requires Ubuntu's ancient version of ffmpeg.

Is there a reasonable way to move the question to superuser, or should I just delete it here and re-ask it there.

Also, it seems like a reasonable question to ask "How do I do this on Ubuntu?" so if possible, I'd like to leave it asked here.

Comment: Note:asking same question in different stack exchange sites is not a good practice

Comment: Note that "how do I do this on Ubuntu" and "How do I do this on Linux" aren't *necessarily* identical questions, @abcd. There can be valid reasons for asking different audiences *similar* questions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really have to *move* anything, since the question on your mind now is a product of the two questions you've asked previously... You might ask,

> #### How can I run "Video for everybody" on Ubuntu without losing the ability to strip metadata?

...or better yet,

> #### How can I run "Video for everybody" without breaking software that depends on Ubuntu builds of ffmpeg?

...And then reference both of your previous questions in describing your predicament. Then [someone like aking1012](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3188/how-do-i-and-should-i-move-a-question-to-superuser/3191#3191) can guide you without having to re-hash what you've already learned.

Comment: [Okay, I've asked that way](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140661/how-can-i-run-video-for-everybody-in-current-ubuntu-i-e-without-specially-co).

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues here.

- Should I cross-post
- Ffmpeg

No you shouldn't cross-post.

If you want to use ffmpeg of multiple versions you can statically compile a later ffmpeg.  If you want libav latest, you're going to get avconv not ffmpeg.